# controlling Agilent 33220A with scpi command in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, automation

A remote connection to the device was made using LAN.I just plug its IP and saw the GUI of the device.
SCPI command manual is shown below.
could you please recommend me a basic C# visual studio manual to actually learn how to connect and send basic commands to the device?
Thanks.
https://ecelabs.njit.edu/student_resources/33220_user_guide.pdf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHbNW.png)

I have tried to read the manual of the device.
In google i tried to look for a manual however they all are talking on a much higher level then i need.
I only need the basic connection and test commands step.
Thanks.